# Export to CSV: Why '\t' is not working, while '\n' works:

Tags: javascript, export-to-csv

Everything gets downloaded, but '\t' is not working, while '\n' works and gets rendered correctly in Excel.

```
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/peace_reports/data.php", function (res) {
      var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(ddd());
        function ddd (){
            var ll = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
                ll += res[i]['Name'] + '\t' + res[i]['ID'] + '\n';
            }
            return ll;
        }

      //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = uri;

      //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
      link.style = "visibility:hidden";
      link.download = "test" + ".csv";

      //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Tried `"` instead of single quotes?

Comment: @Zuzlx, I did, no reaction.

Comment: @Zuzlx Javascript is not like PHP, it treats both quotes the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `.tsv` file, not a `.csv`. CSV is comma separated, TSV is tab separated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values

That might be why it doesn't show up correctly in Excel. Try switching to commas or changing the file type. I recommend switching to commas, since TSV is a pretty rare file format, I think.

Comment: I think Excel tries to detect what delimiter the file is using automatically, although you can tell it explicitly when importing.

Comment: I just replaced '\t' with ',' and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can add "\t," in the csv format

Hope It works....